# submit value for mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material

We have a `mat-autocomplete` input on a form.

The options are populated from a database, these are returns as an ID, String pair.

I would like to allow the user to select based on the string value but submit the ID value with the form for a lookup when posted server side? What is the best solution for this please?

My component.html is;

```
<mat-form-field class="form-group special-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Select a trade" aria-label="Select a trade" matInput formControlName="trade" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" md-menu-class="autocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name">
             <span [innerHTML]="option.name | highlight: toHighlight"></span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Where option has a name and id field.

I have tried adjusting the `[value]="option.name"` to `[value]="option.id"` however this updated the text field in the auto complete to be the id value rather than the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a simple

```
(onSelectionChange)="selectedOption(option)"
```

on `mat-option`, passing the binding of the data to the ts component. Then you can easily decide what value you should pass to the server.

Comment: ok so you are saying I have a local var in the .ts `selectedCategory` for example and then in the captured event set the id to be this? i.e. `this.selectedCatergoy = option.id`

Comment: Exactly! Or you can already capture the value you need calling selectedOption(option.id) and do whatever you need in the ts component

Comment: just to add I fell into this scenario where the event was triggering twice https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4094, but by filtering on the `isUserInput` sorted this issue.

Comment: Nice to hear, I will check the behaviour of that in my project